# How to produce a vectorized function and take a double integral of each?

Tags: r, function, double, integration, vectorization

I have a function and I want to take a double integral of it. The problem is that there are some vectors inside the function. I don't know how to vectorize the function and then integrate of each function over the variables which are not vectors.

```
beta=c(1,2,3)
sigmay=0.1
sigmax1=0.1
sigmay1=0.1
# each of stt, sezz and smm is an identified n element vector

func1 = function(smtheo, sttheo) {
Xtheo=c(1, log(smtheo), log(sezz)) 
mu <- beta %*% Xtheo
ypri=dnorm(log(sttheo), mu, sigmay)
joipri=dnorm(log(stt), log(sttheo), sigmay1)*dnorm(log(smm),log(smtheo), sigmax1) 
return(ypri*joipri)}

int=integral2(func1(smtheo, sttheo), a1, a2, b1, b2)
```

Actually I have n numbers of func1 of each should be integrated over smtheo and stttheo limits. Does anyone know about it?

Comment: what are `a1, a2, b1, b2`?

Comment: also there are some typos, `smtheo` and `smmtheo`, and `sezz`, `stt`, `smm` are not defined.

Comment: @Jeff, a1, a2, b1 and b2 are the lower and upper limits of the double integral and has been defined as :    5, 5.001, 0.5, 30. smtheo and sttheo are the variables of the function. Assume that sezz, stt and smm, as I mentioned in the code, are the vectors each with n elements that have been defined at the beginning.

Comment: I can't run your code and offer a good answer without having all the variables you are using. Perhaps make a small example?

Comment: @Jeff each of `sezz`, `smm` and `stt` is a vector with 1000 elements like `c(1:1000)`. `smtheo` and `sttheo` are the variables of the function. `a1`, `a2`, `b1` and `b2` are the lower and upper limits of the double integral and I defined them in the previous comment

Comment: @Roland, Could you please help me about this?

Comment: You need to correctly implement `func1`, see the documentation for `integrate2` in the `pracma` package (which I assume you are using). "The function fun itself must be fully vectorized: It must accept arrays X and Y and return an array Z = f(X,Y) of corresponding values. If option vectorized is set to FALSE the procedure will enforce this vectorized behavior.". Also the call should be `integral2(func1, a1, a2, b1, b2)`